# Count and Sort Data

Tags: python, pandas

Hi guys after a long long time i am working again with python.

Hope you can help me cause i forgot the most :D

This is the Dataframe I have:

[image]

and what I need is this.

[image]

already build a dataframe and grouped them but i dont know how to count the different values.

```
df2['Model']= df1['Model'].nunique()
df2['Type'] = df2['Model'].map(df1['Type'].value_counts())
```

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: we need input as text or code to answer your question. : [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
out = (df.groupby('Model')['Type'].agg(['count', 'nunique'])
       .set_axis(['Count', 'different Values'], axis=1)
       .reset_index()
)
```

out:

```
  Model  Count  different Values
0     A      2                 2
1     B      3                 2
2     C      1                 1
3     D      1                 1
```

Another approach

```
dict_func = {'Count': ('Type', 'count'), 'different Values': ('Type', 'nunique')}
out = df.groupby('Model', as_index=False).agg(**dict_func)
```

same result

---

**Example Code**

we need input as text or code to answer your question.

from next time make it text, not image

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'Model': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
         'Type': ['W', 'C', 'V', 'V', 'G', 'H', 'I']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

Comment: Ok thank you i wil ad code next time :)
Is it possible to get an explantation of the .agg?

Comment: @credenco run this code : `df.groupby('Model', as_index=False).agg(Count=('Type', 'count'))` agg argument(new column name) = (column to apply function, function). but 'different values' have space so i make dictionary and use **kwarg

Comment: I have a big dataset in csv with many informations. is a dataframe alswas the best way to manipulate the data for my next steps?